# Setting up my first prometheus federation

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-node-exporter

this is my first question sorry if i did something wrong. (english isn't my main language)

Im implementing my first prometheus federation system and i don't have ideia how to comunicate two servers that are in diferent networks and firewall.

I don't know if i have to configure both firewalls or if i have to configure my prometheus config file.

This is my global config for my prometheus. And im using node-exporter to get the metrics.

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s # Set the scrape interval to every 15 seconds. Default is every 1 minute.
  evaluation_interval: 15s # Evaluate rules every 15 seconds. The default is every 1 minute.
  # scrape_timeout is set to the global default (10s).

# Alertmanager configuration
alerting:
  alertmanagers:
    - static_configs:
        - targets:
          # - alertmanager:9093

# Load rules once and periodically evaluate them according to the global 'evaluation_interval'.
rule_files:
  # - "first_rules.yml"
  # - "second_rules.yml"

# A scrape configuration containing exactly one endpoint to scrape:
# Here it's Prometheus itself.
scrape_configs:
  # The job name is added as a label `job=<job_name>` to any timeseries scraped from this config.
  - job_name: "prometheus"
    static_configs:
      - targets: ["192.168.0.223:9090"]

  - job_name: "node"
    scrape_interval: 15s
    scrape_timeout: 10s
    static_configs:
      - targets:
        - 192.168.0.223:9100
        - 18.230.81.178:9100
        - 189.90.67.24:9100
```

[This is what appears in my prometheus web localhost.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxK6P.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is not related to Prometheus itself, you must guarantee that Prometheus can scrape this addresses in the port 9100, or else it won't work.

I suggest that you test if your Prometheus instance can access this addresses on another ports and if there is a firewall rule specific for port 9100. For this to work, you must at least be able to communicate to port 80 in these networks, so you can set up a federation architecture. This way, you would have one Prometheus instance in each network scraping for your nodes, and a centralized instance scraping your federated Prometheus in port 80(or another one that is accessible!).